# Ranking numbers columns in Excel without using the Rank Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, ranking

I want to see if there are any creative and efficient ways to rank columns based on their value without using the rank function in excel.  Instead of going =Rank(B4,B2:B6,1) what could you do? and no macros. haha

Comment: What does rank do that is not what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the lowest value ranked 1 (as your suggested formula will do) then you can use COUNTIF like this in row 2 copied down

`=COUNTIF(B$2:B$6,"<"&B2)+1`

reverse the < to RANK largest value as 1

Comment: Thanks alot! This is exactly what we needed in our lab.